# My wordpress header disappears when I am on some page

Tags: wordpress, header, amp-html

I have a Wordpress site and custom theme where I integrate AMP. I use different `get_headers()` for my custom pages.

When I navigate to projekte's page from homepage, my header is missing.

This is [my site](http://lastan.de)

[image: here is my screenshot]

Comment: I can see the header on projekte. Can you provide more context on where is the header not showing? Like OS, browser, steps to reproduce.

Comment: win7 chrome... homepage -> projekte, news->projekte, team->projekte...

Comment: http://www.lastan.de/projekte/ I can see the header on win7 chrome.

Comment: I cannot.. but only with CTRL + F5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example for custom headers:**

File: `header-custom.php` 
Code: `get_header('custom');`

For this example make sure that your custom headers are located in theme root.

Comment: for the Projekte's page.(archive-projekte.php).. i have created this: get_header('page'); ( header-page.php )... It is that wrong that I named like this?

Comment: Where are located both files?

Comment: Which header are you expecting? I see your navbar with the logo on the left. So the header exists on DOM. Did you try to empty your browser cache?

Comment: Yeah... you are very right..I have totally forgotten about that... Thanks a lot... You saved me alot of time

Answer (score 0):

just change your function. It is 
get_header not get_headers so please follow this documentation.

**get_header()**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

Comment: Thanks for help.. but my functions is well... in my header of projekte, I have get_header('projekte'); ... and I also have created header-projekte.php

Comment: but in firebug your header is not show all the content like your menu items and all. So you provide your header code for troubleshoot the issue.